# Best time complexity for calculating the next, unique graph.

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity

Whats the best time complexity, for a known algorithm, that when called generates the next, unique, graph, in order of node count?

For example, the first result being the only single node graph, I request a new graph, it takes 2 units of time as that graph has two nodes, I request the next and it takes 3 units of time giving me 3 nodes in a line. The forth also has 3 nodes, joined in a triangle, so this call still takes just 3 units of time, etc...

This example, that probably has better time complexity than the best available algorithm, takes *linear time for the number of nodes in the output graph*.

---

More specifically, to answer TravisJ, To put it another way, an element in the *set of all graphs*, where no other element has fewer nodes, that has not yet been output by the algorithm.

Put another way, the next graph is a graph with the current number of nodes that has not yet been generated. The number of nodes may need to be increased by one, allowing for a slightly larger graph to be the result.

---

If this needed to be done with an exhaustive search, I could imagine the time complexity being rather steep, such as exponential or factorial.

Comment: In order to answer this question sufficiently, you need to better describe how your algorithm generates "the next graph."  Or at least how "the next graph" is defined.

Comment: Labeled graphs with $n$ nodes can be indexed by/generated from binary strings of length ${n \choose 2}$ (because there are $2^{n \choose 2}$ labeled graphs with $n$ nodes), but if you only want non-isomorphic graphs, that's a whole different story.

Comment: Yes, the vanilla non-isomorphic, connected, unlabelled sort.